# Insert one black space after the second charactor

Tags: javascript, regex

How can you insert **one** black space after the second character?

Upon keyup, the first `replace()` ensures the user can not enter anything other than numbers.

The second `replace()` attempts to add a single space after the second digit. After sourcing the [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), I can not figure out how to make this happen once. Right now, a space is entered after every 2 digits

keyup event:

```
event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{2})/g, '$1 ').trim();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use start of the line anchor like `^(.{2})`, so that it would capture the first two characters or otherwise it captures any two characters from anywhere.

```
event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/^(.{2})/m, '$1 ').trim();
```

Comment: Perfect, whats is the difference is using the global 'g' and 'm' replace(/^(.{2})/m, '$1 ')

Comment: wouldn't that add more and more spaces after entering the 3rd, 4th, 5th digits?

Comment: It doesn't, I just checked. Am curious to know

Comment: it does for me - don't forget it's called every keystroke

Comment: @JaromandaX no it won't since we added the start of the line anchor.

Comment: @meteorBuzz because it will do a single replace , so no need for global flag.